# Getting error msg in web .xml page,how to resolve this one

Tags: java, sql

Multiple annotations found at this line:
- There is '1' error in 'javaee_7.xsd'.
- Start tag of element 
- schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.xsd/cache/www.w3.org/
2001/xml.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the
document is not xsd:schema.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens to me too and I ignore it.

If you develop your project normally, after saving it the error disappears as long as you do not reopen the web.xml.

If it bothers you and you want it to disappear, delete a p from the web-app and write it again, then click save

Comment: What do you mean by "a p"?

Comment: Sorry, I need to improve my level of English.
What I wanted to say is that I delete any letter that is in the second line, as for example from "web-app" I delete a "p" and it remains "web-ap" and then I write the "p" again, "web-app", and I click save, and the error disappears as long as you do not reopen the web.xml.